# Does the Blackberry browser support offline web apps?

Tags: html, blackberry, offline, offlineapps, offline-caching

Does anyone know if the standard browser in Blackberry OS6 supports cache manifests and offline browsing? If so, would it be able to handle caching around 30 pages of data?

The reason is I need to make a call between developing a native app or a web app and this will be the deal breaker for the (quicker, easier) web app idea.

Thanks in advance for any help/advice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found this:

http://docs.blackberry.com/en/developers/deliverables/18169/Standards_support_in_60_browser_1120158_11.jsp

via [@alex_gibson](http://twitter.com/alex_gibson) on twitter - looks like offline web apps should be okay.

Don't know if there's going to be any limitations with the amount of data you can cache for offline use but if the project goes ahead I'll write up any findings :)

Answer (score 0):

I think `Opera Mini`/`Opera Mobile` for BlackBerry supports this (not sure about the native browser, which is kind of a POS anyway).

Web apps for mobile devices tend to not be very good - they normally really don't compare to native apps, and this is especially so for BlackBerry.  On the other hand, BB development is a big PITA, so perhaps a web app is the way to go.